# Substitution breaking the scope

Tags: replacement, scoping

A novice's problem, perhaps: it seems that `/.` substitution does weird things to the scope.

```
In[1]:= alpha := -0.6 + 0.05*k /. k -> 1

In[2]:= mu[k_] := Integrate[x^alpha*x^k, {x, 0, 1}]

In[3]:= Table[mu[k], {k, 0, 2}]

Out[3]= {2.5, 0.689655, 0.4}

In[4]:= Table[mu[p], {p, 0, 2}]

Out[4]= {2.22222, 0.689655, 0.408163}
```

Why does `Table` iterated over `k` produce different results from `Table` iterated over `p`? And what exactly does `Table` over `k`compute?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Do not paste In[], Out[] to your question it it makes it easier to copy your code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that in the first table (`Table[mu[k], {k, 0, 2}]`) the rule substitution `(ReplaceAll)` does not happen and `k` in `alpha` is always take whatever `k` came from `Table`.

to check that try:

```
alpha := -0.6 + 0.05*1
```

and then

```
Table[mu[k], {k, 0, 2}]
(*{2.22222, 0.689655, 0.408163}*)
```

if you want to go for more details, check in your example this:

```
Table[mu[k], {k, 0, 2}]//Trace

Table[mu[p], {p, 0, 2}]//Trace
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `Trace` outputs lots of stuff I don't know how to interpret yet, unfortunately. Also, I have noticed that if I replace `:=` with `=` in the definition of `alpha`, the problem goes away. Why is that so?